# LAMBDA current_timestamp towards Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

Question is very simple:
We are executing select current_timestamp from lambda to PostgreSQL aurora (which is set to america/New_york timezone).

Scenario:

When we execute select Current_timestamp directly in PostgreSQL Server, it is giving the time in EST.
But when we execute the same form Lambda, it is giving UTC time zone.

I know that Lambda timezone is UTC.
But I am confused here, because am picking up this piece of code "select Current_timestamp" from dynamoDB and passing it as a string through lambda towards PostgreSQL. And I can see this statement is exciting in PostgreSQL too. It should pick up the timezone  of PostgreSQL. Not sure why it is picking Lambda.

Need to fix this and I need to execute this statement from Lambda and get the Current_timestamp of PostgreSQL(Not LAMBDA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_timestamp` returns the timestamp formatted for the current session, which may be in UTC.  You have a few options:

1. `SELECT current_timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York';` This is the most explicit.
2. Start each session with `SET TIME ZONE 'America/New_York';`
3. `ALTER USER youruser SET TIME ZONE 'America/New_York';` This will default the user to this time zone, but the client can still override this.

Comment: Initially I thought the same, But I am executing select current_timestamp manually from CST through pgadmin which is returning EST.
However, I will try your suggestions

Comment: It's quite possible that whatever language you are using in lambda is setting a session time zone.  Your pgadmin session is definitely not doing that.

Comment: It wasn't one hour ahead of EST?  America/New_York is currently in EDT, which should be one hour ahead of EST.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion 1 worked.
However, before posting here, I tried your suggestion 1 but like this.
SELECT current_timestamp at time zone 'EST';
which gave me result 1 hour behind . I understand why it showed like that after reading your comment. Very helpful.